# How to show .gitignore file in the sidebar in Sublime Text 2/3

Tags: sublime-text-2, sublime-text-3

I want to see my project .gitignore file. It's always hidden. Why it's hidden and how to fix this?

Comment: Files with names starting with a dot are hidden on Unix-like systems. You can switch between files in ST by pressing Ctrl+P and typing filename, it's faster than using a sidebar and *.gitignore* is visible there. You don't have to type entire name, ST is using fuzzy search.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Unix, as @gronostaj said, files proceeded with a `.` are hidden by default (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd> toggles this in many environments).  However, in Sublime - you can manually control what types of files are shown/hidden separate from what the system default is.

For you to change your settings you need to adjust your `User Preferences` file with the following:

```
{
    "folder_exclude_patterns": [".svn", ".hg", "CVS"],
    "file_exclude_patterns": ["*.pyc", "*.pyo", "*.exe", "*.dll", "*.obj","*.o", "*.a", "*.lib", "*.so", "*.dylib", "*.ncb", "*.sdf", "*.suo", "*.pdb", "*.idb", ".DS_Store", "*.class", "*.psd", "*.db", "*.sublime-workspace"]
}
```

Add/remove as necessary from there.

On Mac, your preferences are under `Sublime Text > Preference > Settings - User`.  I don't recall the menu structure on my windows box, but it's probably under `Tools`.

For me:

[image]